# use multiple form in a view. which is post to the different action with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Getting trouble with known at the title.

I have two forms in `new.html.erb` view. One is `form_for`, other one is `form_tag`, both as partials.

`form_for` is to save some data to models.

`form_tag` is to do little action with params. and give back the processed data to partilal(js). here I'm stuck. this not working.

`form_tag` is not working. after submitting, the action "`urlchanger`" don't reflect any data to partial "`urlchanged`". in My plan, this should get `@url`, but get errors (detail below).

This is the error respowned by submitting form_tag.

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/notes/new"
..
Processing by Rambulance::ExceptionsApp#not_found as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "url"=>"<iframe src=\"http://hogehoge.com/hoge" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no></iframe>", "urlchanger"=>"変換"}
Rendered errors/not_found.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 66ms (Views: 48.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

as the non partial. everything works fine.
but, I want them to work in single view.

```
notes
--new.html.erb
----_form.html.erb
----_urlchanger.html.erb
----_urlchanged.js
----_urlchanger.js.erb

!-------------notes/new.html.erb-------------!
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= render 'urlchanger' %>

!-------------notes/_urlchanger.html.erb-------------!
<%= bootstrap_form_tag(controller: "notes", action: "urlchanger", remote: true ) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :url, hide_label: true, :class => "form-control", placeholder: "ペーストエリア" %>
<%= f.submit "変換", data: { disable_with: '送信中'} %>
<div id="urlchanged" >
  <%= render "urlchanged" %>
</div>
<% end %>

!-------------notes/_urlchanged.html.erb-------------!
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= @url %>">

!-------------notes/_urlchanger.js.erb-------------!
$('#urlchanged').html('<%= j(render("urlchanged")) %>');

!-------------routes-------------!
resources :notes do
collection do
  post :create
  post :urlchanger
end
end
!-------------Notes controller-------------!
def urlchanger
  url = params[:url]
  if /(https?:\/\/\D*\w*)/ =~ url
    @url = $&
  end
end
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you describe what is not working? Is the form not being submitted or not rendering or the partial not showing?

Comment: the submitted works. rendering works. but the partial don't change anything by submitting.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you change your `notes/_urlchanger.js.erb` to `notes/urlchanger.js.erb`?

OR try this

```
  def urlchanger
    url = params[:url]
    if /(https?:\/\/\D*\w*)/ =~ url
      @url = $&
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      # format.html { redirect_to(:back) } # no idea what you might want to do here
      format.js { render partial: "notes/urlchanger" }
    end
  end
```

Comment: tried both. nothing changes. getting same error. ><

Comment: could you use change to: `bootstrap_form_tag(urlchanger_notes_path, remote: true ) do |f|`

Comment: do you have this on Github or something?

Comment: it works now. but don't cleary understand why it works.

Comment: I meant the answer below. however, Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

solved problem!!
I don't know why it works ('A')
But like the code blow works good.

```
---------------Note.controller----------------------
def urlchanger
  url = params[:url]
  if /(https?:\/\/\D*\w*)/ =~ url
    @url = $&
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    # format.html { redirect_to(:back) } # no idea what you might want to do here
    format.js
  end
end

------------------notes/_urlchanger.html.erb-------------------
<%= bootstrap_form_tag( url: notes_urlchanger_path, remote: true ) do |f| %>
```